# finding the script that runs on background for a html request

Tags: apache

I am trying to find the script that runs on background when a html request is made to the apache server. I have access to the server and I need to alter the script. I am new to apache. I tried checking the error_log with debug log level but could not find any log abt the script. How can I identify the script?
thanks
bala